# Targeting Only One Other Class Within the Same Parent With Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover

I'm trying to affect only one class by hovering another element withing the same parent. There are many parents/elements with the same class name and I only need to target one inside of each to implement a hover effect. I'm trying to use .find(), but it doesn't work for some reason. And if I don't use .find(), it starts targeting all ".team-title" class elements on a page.

```
<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-memeber"></div>
  <div class="team-title"></div>
</div>

<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-member"></div>
  <div class="team-title"></div>
</div>

<div class="team-parent">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

```js
$(".team-member").hover(function() {
  $("this").find(".team-title").animate({"marginLeft": "15px"}, 400);
}, function() {
  $("this").find(".team-title").animate({"marginLeft": "0px"}, 400);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to use `this` as a keyword, not a string. Secondly `find()` is used to locate child elements, whereas the element you're trying to target is a sibling, as such you can use `next()`, like this:

```js
$(".team-member").hover(function() {
  $(this).next(".team-title").animate({
    "marginLeft": "15px"
  }, 400);
}, function() {
  $(this).next(".team-title").animate({
    "marginLeft": "0px"
  }, 400);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-member">Member 1</div>
  <div class="team-title">Team 1</div>
</div>
<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-member">Member 2</div>
  <div class="team-title">Team 2</div>
</div>
```

That being said, there is no need for JS here, as what you're trying to achieve can be done more effectively in CSS:

```css
.team-title {
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: margin 0.4s;
}

.team-member:hover + .team-title {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-member">Member 1</div>
  <div class="team-title">Team 1</div>
</div>
<div class="team-parent">
  <div class="team-member">Member 2</div>
  <div class="team-title">Team 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I ended up using .find()  on a parent class and it all worked.